# Unable to format a encrypted micro sdxc card

Tags: micro-sd-card

I have an encrypted 128GB micro sd card. I reinserted it into my phone and went into settings, storage where it shows sd card under it, it says "corrupt" I tap it and it tells me I have to set it up in order to use it. So I proceeded it got to about 20% but when I looked back at the screen it was back on the settings screen. Not showing the sd card was even still mounted in the phone...... any help is appreciated!

Just to add I also did try using the "clean all" using the command prompt. It did not work.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the card in a different device?

Comment: Yes I tried instering it into my mni SD card port on my laptop. It prompt me to format the card. So I clicked "format" then select "start" on the next screen that popped up. It started formatting it but ends up saying "unable to format"

Comment: Then your card is bad and needs to be replaced. Even if you were able to repair the card it could no longer be trusted to reliably store data.